Не могу подключиться к серверу по своему локальному IP Asp.net
Я запускаю свой проект Asp.Net он открывается по  localhost всё ок ,но локальный адрес моего пк 192.168.1.110 и к нему я подключиться не могу ,брэндмауэр выключен ,у меня статический ip и я пытаюсь разрешить доступ из вне ,но я даже из локалки не могу зайти ,порты на роутере настроены ,к примеру я открыл майнкрафт сервер чисто для теста скачал и там всё ок всё работает ,а проект asp нет

Если вы просто нажали "Плей" кнопку в студии и думаете, что это ваш сайт, то сильно ошибаетесь. Для отладки любого проекта, используете тот инструмент, который в первую очередь заточен именно на решение данной задачи. Запуская сайт под отладкой, у вас разворачивается IIS Express - упрощенный веб сервер, который создан именно для отладки вашего проекта, и который по умолчанию настроен только на localhost. Хотите видеть сайт за пределами своего компьютера, настраивайте IIS Express, а еще лучше - опубликуйте его.

Сервер, когда слушает порт, он может его слушать на определенном IP или на любом доступном IP. Если сервер слушает только 127.0.0.1, то на адрес 192.168.х.х невозможно будет к нему подключиться.
